# Changing id field to slug field in django

Tags: python, django

Everything worked fine when I used `<int:pk>` in urlconfig to view `DetailView` page of my *blogs*.

```py
# included from urls.py in main dir
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='blog_index'),
    path('blogs', views.allblogs.as_view(), name='blogs'),
    path('blogs/<int:pk>', views.blogDetail.as_view(), name='blog-detail'),
]
# result url example 127.0.0.1:8000/blog/blogs/2
```

I later changed my mind to display the url as `127.0.0.1:8000/blogs/new-blog` instead of an `int` value. To achieve this result I made the following changes to *urls.py*,

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='blog_index'),
    path('blogs', views.allblogs.as_view(), name='blogs'),
    re_path(r'^blogs/(?P<slug_me>[-\w]+)$', views.blogDetail.as_view(), name='blog-detail'),
]
```

and following additions to *models.py*:

```py
class Blog(models.Model):
    ...

    slug = models.SlugField(default=slugify('iamslug'+str(id)))

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Blog, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog-detail', kwargs={'slug':self.slug, 'id':self.id})
```

But now when I access `127.0.0.1:8000/blog/blogs`, it throws the following error:

```py
Reverse for 'blog-detail' with keyword arguments '{'slug': 'djangodbmodelsfieldscharfield', 'id': 1}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog\\/blogs/(?P<slug_me>[-\\w]+)$']
```

And at `127.0.0.1:8000/blog/blogs/new-blog`, it throws this error:

```py
Generic detail view blogDetail must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.
```

I am unable to move forward. I tried changing `urls.py` to include *slug* keyword, which results in **Page Not Found**.

```py
# changed re_path(r'^blogs/(?P<slug_me>[-\w]+)$', views.blogDetail.as_view(), name='blog-detail') to
re_path(r'^blogs/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)$', views.blogDetail.as_view(), name='blog-detail')
```

Comment: have you changed view function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='blog_index'),
    path('blogs', views.allblogs.as_view(), name='blogs'),
    path('blogs/<slug:slug>/', views.blogDetail.as_view(), name='blog-detail'),
```

your `models.py` is suppose to look like this

```
class Blog(models.Model):
...

slug = models.SlugField()

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.slug:
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
    return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('blog-detail', kwargs={'slug':self.slug})
```

Use slugfield strictly and check out django [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/) for urls pathing

Comment: @maddypie update me if it worked and you can mark for other users to know

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response. THIS WORKS!! Apparently, the ```kwargs``` in ```get_absolute_url``` caused the problem. It throws a ```NoReverseMatch``` error at /blog/blogs when I include ```'id':str(self.id)``` in ```kwargs```. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: check out this [article](https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-slug-tutorial) it provides the extensive differences btw using `kwargs={'id': self.id}` and `kwargs={'slug':self.slug}`....hope this helps

Comment: For anyone getting a ```NameError: name 'slugify' is not defined``` add the following top of **models.py**: ```from django.utils.text import slugify```.